# PySpark sum of column recomputed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like:

```
A | B
-----
1 | 2
2 | 3
3 | 4
```

(values totally arbitrary)

I want a dataframe that is exactly like that but has another column which is SUM(B), like overall sum of column B without any grouping or anything. The result would be:

```
A | B | SUM(B)
--------------
1 | 2 | 9
2 | 3 | 9
3 | 4 | 9
```

How can this be achieved? I tried something like:

```
df = df.alias('df') # alias is df
df = df.select(
   'df.*',
   sum(col('df.B'))
)
```

But this does not work since it complains that I am doing sum without grouping. Is this possible some way in Pyspark?

Comment: Use sum over Window

Comment: @blackbishop, an example would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious approach would be to use a window function like this:

```py
win = Window.orderBy(f.lit(1))
df.withColumn("SUM(B)", f.sum("B").over(win)).show()
```

Yet, you would obtain the following warning

> WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.

It means that by using a window function without partionning causes the entire dataframe to be sent to one single executor. It is exactly what we want to avoid with spark for obvious performance reasons.

A better solution, that does not involve sending all the data on one executor, would be to compute the sum and then add it to the dataframe with `lit` like this:

```py
sum_b = df.select(f.sum("B")).first()[0]
df.withColumn("SUM(B)", f.lit(sum_b)).show()
```

Comment: Doesnt that also send it to one executor? Because when do you `first()` I believe it does a `collect()` doesnt it?

Comment: With a non partitionned window, **all** the rows of your dataframe end up in the same partition, and the sum is computed there. With the other approach, the sum is computed in //, and only its result, a dataframe with one row of one column is collected to the driver.